# How can I use context variables to pass information to Promise functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The use case here is that I want to be able to fill the value of 'content' in with input from another source, say a textbox.  So a user can enter some text hit "analyze" and then it'll send the text out in a Post Body and display the return.  I have been able to get this to work in both R and Python, but now I'm trying to gain an understanding of how to get this to work in Javascript.

I am trying to pass a variable into a Promise / .thenable function in JavaScript. I am pasting the example code below. What I would like to be able to do is pass the function `start` a variable to use as the content part of the JSON, specifically...

I would like to change this part of the function:

```
return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
    'document': {
        'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
        'content': 'I had a wonderful time with my children when I took them to the park.'
    }
});
```

to something like this:

```
return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
    'document': {
        'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
        'content': thisIsTheTextToAnalyze
    }
});
```

I have read something about context passing from this [link](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises).   From what I've read there I think I have to alter the code so that it uses the

```
gapi.client.request
```

methodology instead of the one I"m using below - which is just using

```
gapi.init, 
gapi.load, and 
gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment.
```

Is that correct? If so, can someone help me figure out how to format that

```
gapi.client.request
```

function call or point me to the documentation to explain it?  I'm not a javascript programmer and I'm bumbling around, and I can't find any demos that explain it.

Here is the full code.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>
  function start() {
    // Initializes the client with the API key and the Translate API.
    gapi.client.init({
      'apiKey': myApiKey,
      'discoveryDocs': ['https://language.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
    }).then(function() {

      // Executes an API request, and returns a Promise.
      // The method name `language.translations.list` comes from the API discovery.
      // gapi.client.language.translations.list
      // method = annotateText

      return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
        'document': {
          'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
          'content': 'I had a wonderful time with my children when I took them to the park.'
        }
      });
    }).then((results) => {

      const sentiment = results.result.documentSentiment;
      alert(`Document sentiment:`);
      alert(`  Score: ${sentiment.score}`);
      alert(`  Magnitude: ${sentiment.magnitude}`);
      const sentences = results.result.sentences;
      sentences.forEach((sentence) => {
        alert(`Sentence: ${sentence.text.content}`);
        alert(`  Score: ${sentence.sentiment.score}`);
        alert(`  Magnitude: ${sentence.sentiment.magnitude}`);
      });
    });

    return(documentSentiment.score);
  };

  // Loads the JavaScript client library and invokes `start` afterwards.
  // gapi.load('client', start);
  $(function (){
    // ...
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following up on some of the suggestions from Aaron, I've tried

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
    <script>
      function start(content) {
        return function ()
        {
        gapi.client.init({
          'apiKey': DontchaWishYouKnew,
          'discoveryDocs': ['https://language.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1'],
        }).then(function() {
          return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
            'document': {
                      'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
                      'content': content
                   }
          });
        }).then((results) => {


        const sentiment = results.result.documentSentiment;
        alert(`Document sentiment:`);
        alert(`  Score: ${sentiment.score}`);
        alert(`  Magnitude: ${sentiment.magnitude}`);

      })

        return(documentSentiment.score);

   }
    };

      // Loads the JavaScript client library and invokes `start` afterwards.
      $(function (){
         gapi.load('client', start('this doesnt work'));

      }
        )
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure, just replace the constant string with a variable that is in scope and has the expected value, it will work. This has nothing to do with promises or "contexts" or anything.

Comment: Hey Bergi,
That's a great answer, except I'm a javascript newbie so I don't understand the concept of 'scope' in this case.  Are you saying I could make it a global variable, for example?

Comment: Yes, that or a local variable or probably a parameter of `start` if you want to *pass* it to the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `start` function is called by another `gapi` function ... `gapi.load('client', start)`. There isn't any way to pass a parameter value when calling it this way.

Return a function:

```
function start(content) { // Called before being used as a parameter
  return function () { // Called by 'gapi.load' so no parameter passed
    gapi.client.init({
      // ...
    }).then(function() {
      // ...
      return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
        'document': {
          'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
          'content': content
        }
      });
    }).then((results) => {
      // ...
    });

    return(documentSentiment.score);
  }
};
```

Usage:

```
gapi.load('client', start('I had a wonderful time with my children.'));
gapi.load('client', start('A wonderful time with my children I had.'));
```

---

> even better do the `init` once, and then be able to pass it different values for `start`.

Scope it:

```
var start = (function () { // Called immediately to scope (share) 'init'
  var init;
  return function (content) { // Called before being used as a parameter
    return function () { // Called by 'gapi.load' so no parameter passed
      if (!init) {
        init = gapi.client.init({
          // ...
        });
      }
      init.then(function() {
        // ...
        return gapi.client.language.documents.analyzeSentiment({
          'document': {
            'type': 'PLAIN_TEXT',
            'content': content
          }
        });
      }).then((results) => {
        // ...
      });

      return(documentSentiment.score);
    }
  }
})();
```

Usage:

```
// No change!
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work (or I don't know how to make it work?). The start function is called by another gapi function called gapi.load, which is executed as follows 

    gapi.load('client', start).  There isn't anyway to pass a parameter value when calling it this way.  I'll add this to the orginal question.

Comment: Ah, I see now. You want to call `gapi.load('client', start);` multiple times but with different `content` in `start` each time?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  

Or honestly, even better do the init once, and then be able to pass it different values for start. But yes.

Comment: I've tried to implement your suggestion, but I can't get it to work. I"m going to paste the full code that I've submitted in the question part above to update it.

Comment: I'm running it on a web server and executing it in a web browser (Chrome).  If I replace the variable content with a constant like 'I love taking my children to the park!', it doesn't return any value with the extra bit of code you suggested "return function(content) {...}}"; regardless of how I call said function. It returns no value.

Comment: The use case is basically that I want to be able to have a text box, have the user enter some text in it - hit a button that says "Analyze", and then have it send that entered text to Google and then display the resulting sentiment.

Comment: `return function(content) {...}}` is a different solution - you'll have to replace the entire `start`. Did the top part work?

Comment: Yes! It's fantastic!